# Are there any free alternatives to the Ranorex library (Python, Windows)?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation

I am interested in the Python one. I wish to automate some GUI under Windows. What is the best open source library for that with no strings attached? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [pyWinAuto](http://pywinauto.openqa.org/).

Comment: Thanks Alex ... do you consider it the best choice or is it the one you found? By the way, I went through the unbounded prime generator code that prints the dictionary for the first 20 steps and finally had a "Duh!" moment. I too find the link you supplied to be most readable, hence most Pythonic.

Comment: @Hamish, didn't make an exhaustive study of Windows GUI automation: I rarely program for Windows and when I do pyWinAuto has met my modest needs (I also do have all the packages it needs -- many today are part of the standard library). The page whose URL I gave does have pointers to other such utilities for comparison, but I have had no need to research them!-)

Answer (score 1):

There's [WATSUP](http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html), but I've not tried it yet myself.

I've also heard of pyWinAuto, although the link I have is to [pyWinAuto on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/).